# Security Issues regarding using Ruby on Rails or Django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, security

I implemented a website using rails recently. However, is there any security related thing I should include in my controller or view ?

For example, checking the `paras` variable before actually using them, add csrf token in form.

Comment: Thats the point of `permit` and `peotect_from_forgery`. So its builtin.

Comment: This question is too broad, but here's a good place to start: [Rails security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)